# How do I set the default format of a label to a currency format?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the format of a label to a currency format but I can't figure out how. It doesn't have a string format like text blocks have so I am wondering if there is any property or a way that I can make a custom format so it could look like currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `ContentStringFormat` property.